# Copy constructor invocation in loop

Tags: c++

I use the following classes:

```
#include <list>

class A {
public:
    A();
    A(const A&);
    ~A();
    list<A> createCopies();

private:
    int *cells;
};

A::A() {
    this->cells = new int[5];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        this->cells[i] = 0;
    }
}

A::(const A &oldA) {
    this->cells = new int[5];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        this->cells[i] = oldA.cases[i];
    }
}

A::~A() {
    delete[] this->cells;
}

list<A> A::createCopies() {
    list<A> listA;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        A newA = A(*this); // or A newA(*this)?
        A.cells[i] = 1;
        listA.push_back(newA);
    }

    return listA;
}
```

However, the compiler seems to always push the same object in the list. I thought the call to the copy constructor would prevent that...

Am I wrong ? Do I need to use the `new A` way of creating objects (and thus taking the pain of managing their destruction somewhere)?

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile (you can't assign to `cells` since it's defined as an array). Based on what you seem to want, you shouldn't need to define a copy constructor at all (i.e., the compiler will synthesize a copy constructor that copies `cells` correctly).

Comment: -1 for fake code.  No compiler would pass this.  Not even Turbo C++ or Visual C++ 6.0. How can we be expected to help you solve the problems in your code if you don't actually show us your code?

Comment: The code has been corrected. Sorry for introduced mistakes

Answer (score 1):

You run into undefined behavior because you forgot

```
return listA;
```

You're better off using a `std::array` though. If you choose to keep this approach, you'll also want an assignment operator.

I'm assuming your actual member is `int* cells;`.

Comment: Isn't a compiler supposed to complain about a missing return statement? A Java compiler will, but I don't recall about C++.

Comment: @Code-Guru Some compilers will, for visual studio i think it is an error. But for others they might just give a warning.

Comment: @user573152 if you don't post the actual code but just some memory of what it is, there's no way anyone can help you.